# Appcelerator filesystem and deploying data files at build time

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I need to install an iOS and Android app built with Appcelerator Alloy which contains a large number of photos (about 200Mb in total). From time to time the user will be able to download new photos from a remote server, but only at the rate of about 10Mb each time.
I have built the app and it works fine using the Resources directory, but I now realise this can only be read (not deleted or updated) by the app on devices.  I am not clear about where in the project filesystem I should put the photo files so that they will be in the ApplicationDataDirectory when the app is installed. Do I need to somehow move/copy all the data from the resources directory into the ApplicationDataDirectory at build time? Seems a bit long-winded....
Sorry a bit of a long question, but can't find an answer anywhere!
Any help or advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using applicationDataDirectory.
I've a lot of pictures, at the download time, in order to the device don't run out of memory, after downloading the image file, wait one second and goes to the next one, every time that I download those images, I'm deleting the old ones.

Delete old ones and its folder, create a new folder:

```
var path = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'products');

if(path.exists()) path.deleteDirectory(true);

path.createDirectory();
```

After downloading the image:

```
Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'products'),'image.png').write(this.responseData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Ricardo, but I really wanted to know about deployment of photos at install time and where to store the images in the project folders prior to the build / install and how to move them (?) so they can be used from the ApplicationDataDirectory.

Comment: Before installing the app on a device? your image files are placed in assets folder, then, you use them like '/imagename.png', you don't need to copy them to resources directory or application directory. You could save them in the application directory, 'write' a ImageView with the image property set like '/imagename.png'

Comment: Ricardo, my problem is that I need to be able to delete and add to photos as well, so they can't go in the Resources folder. What I'm unclear about is where to put files in the project hierarchy so they will be in the application data directory when the app is on a device?

Comment: If you have images inside the assets folder or Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory the images are read-only, if you save the images in Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory you can read, write, delete etc...

Comment: Thats what I found. But where do I keep the images in the project before install so they will be in Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory for the app.?Or do I have to create a copy/move routine that is run at install time?

Comment: Ah ok, that I don't think if it's possible, after building the project, your assets go to the Resources folder, I don't know if has the same path as the  Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, either way, as you know, both are read-only, . You could use the assets folder at the first ussage, and then, after the first sync use the applicationDataDirectory or as you said, if you are doing a loop to the applicationDataDirectory files you should copy them.

Comment: console.log(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory) -> /Users/ricardo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/41E7AAE3-6950-4FD1-ADAF-4CB14CE28BA2/data/Containers/Data/Application/691EAC60-8B3F-42B4-93AF-83658A1B2E15/Documents/
 & console.log(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory) -> /Users/ricardo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/41E7AAE3-6950-4FD1-ADAF-4CB14CE28BA2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3627D1AD-95AA-41A2-966C-596810703EBA/Mobile Sales.app/